# Odoo How to develop a workflow in php for the invoice in XML-RPC?

Tags: php, workflow, xml-rpc, invoice, odoo

I try to push my invoice of my ecommerce platform to odoo. (php - xml-rpc)
The invoice is created but I haven't find how to create a workflow to change the status in Odoo.

I found something on internet but I think it's for old and it' doesn't work for Odoo but OpenERP v6 or 7.

nb : the link : http://goo.gl/lBPWnG

```
//validate the invoice
echo "VALIDATE<BR /><BR />";
$conn->workflow('account.invoice', 'invoice_open', $invoice_id);
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

My code in XML-RPC when I create an invoice in Odoo.

```
// **********************************
// Write a new concerning the shipping by the service line
// **********************************
// invoice line
          $shipping_account_id; // id ofaccount shipping 626000

          $val = array (
                          "invoice_id" => new xmlrpcval($invoice_id, "int"),
                          "account_id" => new xmlrpcval($shipping_account_id, "int"),
                          "company_id" => new xmlrpcval($company_id, "int"),
                          "product_id" => new xmlrpcval($odoo_products_id, "string"),
                          "name" => new xmlrpcval('Service postale', "string"),
                          "quantity" => new xmlrpcval('1',"double"),
                          "price_unit" => new xmlrpcval('20',"double"),
                        );


          $client = new xmlrpc_client($server_url . "/xmlrpc/object");
          $client->setSSLVerifyPeer(0);

          $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
          $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($dbname, "string"));
          $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($uid, "int"));
          $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));
          $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("account.invoice.line", "string"));
          $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
          $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($val, "struct"));
          $response = $client->send($msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method which I used to create an invoice from an order and I'm using odoo .

```
public function createInvoiceFromDraft()
    {
        $saleId = $_REQUEST['customerid'];

        $OERP = new OpenERP();
        $OERPUserId =  $OERP->login($_SESSION['OERP-username'], $_SESSION['OERP-password']);

//workflow for confirming the order
        $r = $OERP->workflow('sale.order', 'order_confirm',  $saleId);


        $result = $OERP->workflow('sale.order', 'manual_invoice',  $saleId);

        $fields = array('name');
        $readName = $OERP->searchread(array(array('id','=',$saleId)), 'sale.order', $fields);
        $orderName = $readName[0]['name'];


        $fields = array('id');
        $id = $OERP->searchread(array(array('origin','=',$orderName )), 'account.invoice', $fields);
        $invoiceId = $id[0]['id'];    

        $result .= $OERP->workflow('account.invoice', 'invoice_open', $invoiceId);

        return $result;
    }
```